# Search query with sails waterline

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I am using sailsjs and trying to create a search query based on user's name and/or location. Now I am constructing the query like

```
   var name = "Harry", 
       location = "Toronto";

   User.findByNameLike( name )
       .exec( function( err, tags ){
            return callbackTag ( null, tags );
       } );
```

Now where I can add the findByLocationLike tags. I tried

```
    User.findByNameLike( name )
    User.findByLocationLike( location )
       .exec( function( err, tags ){
            return callbackTag ( null, tags );
       } );
```

But it gave me an error Object has no method named findByLocationLike. I did

```
    console.log( User.findByNameLike( name ) );
```

Interestingly I see a method named findByLocationLike. I am really confused. Anyone has any idea how to join multiple findByLike query in sails waterline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
User.findlike({name: name, location: location}).exec(console.log);
```

this will return all the users with the name harry that live in torronto.

more info:

http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to search using Like. Because when user search we need to deliver matching content.

Comment: I think you van change in my answer "find" with "findlike"

Comment: Actually your one will work if I want to join name and location based on AND clause, but in my case I want to join them using OR. However it was my fault that I was not expressive in my question so I would accept your answer. Please in your answer please edit User.find -> User.findlike; and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4):

So James' answer would work if I try to join name AND location based on AND condition. However in my case I was using OR clause between those.

So after going through the waterline source code I find the following hack to do what I want.

```
User.find({ 
           or :[ 
                { like: { name: '%'+name+'%' } }, { like: { location : '%'+location+'%' } } 
               ] 
           } , function ( err, users ){
        // some code here
    });
```

And this will give me all the user whose name match with either name with name OR location with location.